# Concate two lists in python using extend

Tags: python

**I have two lists given below**

```
l1=[1,2,3,4]
l2=[5,6,7,8]
```

If i perform `l1.extend(l2) and print(l1), output is [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]` as expected but if i assign it to a variable like `b=l1.extend(l2)` and print(b) the output is None.

Can anyone explain this why it is so ?

Comment: Can you explain how `lambda` tag is relevant here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that `l1.extend` updates the object itself (`l1`) and doesn't return anything.

From Python [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html):

```
list.extend(iterable)
Extend the list by appending all the items from the iterable. Equivalent to a[len(a):] = iterable.
```

Answer (score 1):

`extend()` works in place and returns `None` so you get the output of `l1.extend(l2)` returned as `None`.